# Opening a .jar file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, command

I can't open .jar file on Windows 10 (I have tried everything like reinstalling Java and setting the default app to open it to be javaw.exe) and I don't exactly trust jarunner/jarfixer so I want to make a  batch program which would detect whenever a .jar is being opened it would get the path of it and would run java -jar [pathtofile].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to execute this as administrator:

```
ASSOC .jar=jarfile
FTYPE jarfile=c:\java\java.exe -jar "%1" %*
setx PATHEXT "%PATHEXT%;.jar"
```

Just put the correct path to the `java.exe` . Mind that you'll have to keep all your dependencies in the [`%classpath%` vatiable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#BEHCGBFB).

More for [ASSOC](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) and [FTYPE](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) commands.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is related, but I used this tool http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ to make .exe from .jar

Comment: I just need a way to make the .jar executeable